# How to change RDS master password to be managed in RDS secrets without changing the password itself?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-secrets-manager

I'm using the "terraform-aws-modules/rds-aurora/aws" module and the master password looks like this:

```
{
 # Credentials
  manage_master_user_password = false
  master_username = "root"
  master_password = "some random password"
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
{
 # Credentials
  manage_master_user_password = ture
  master_username = "root"
}
```

but I don't want RDS to create a new password, will that change the password? if yes what is the work around?